# export neo4j data to JSON with cURL

Tags: json, http, curl, request, response

`curl -b -j "Content-Type: application/json" -d '["quer
y:"{"MATCH n RETURN n"}]' http://localhost:7474/db/data/
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Content-Type`

Hello,

i want get JSON from. With curl and write it to a local file.
So i can do other things with it.

But when executing this command i get could not resolve Content-Type.

i've tried:

`curl -b -j Content-Type: application/json' without the double quotation mark ("")`

but then i get this as result

`curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Content-Type
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application`

Now i've fixed this syntax error

`curl -b -j -d '["query:"{"MATCH n RETURN n"}]' http://
localhost:7474/db/data/ -o .
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    28    0     0  100    28      0     13  0:00:02  0:00:02 --:--:--    13`

But no data:(

Answer (score 0):

I had success with:
`curl -b -j -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"query":"match n return n limit 10"}}' http://localhost:7474/db/data/cypher`